# Android Firebase Authentication using createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a new user to Firebase via Android and I am getting an error message that doesn't make sense to me. I have the email/password signin enabled in my Firebase console. The error message I am getting says:

> com.example.myproject
>   D/RegisterActivity: validateForm: LoginActivity validateForm started.
>   com.example.myproject
>   I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@xyz123
>
> com.example.myproject W/FirebaseMethods:
>   createUserWithEmail:failure
>       com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ]

My code base is as follows:

```
public class FirebaseMethods {

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMethods";

// declare Firebase auth
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String user;

private Context mContext;

public FirebaseMethods(Context context){
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mContext = context;

    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }
}

/**
 * Register a new username and email to Firebase authentication
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * @param username
 */
public void registerNewEmail(String email, String password, String username){
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUI: LoginActivity updateUI started.");
    if (user != null) {
        /*If the user is already logged in then navigate back to the MainActivity.*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);


    } else {
        //add alternative action here
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you turn ON `authentication` from fire base console ?

Comment: I have it turned on. See updated photo. I think the issue is in my code.

Answer (score 3):

It is not enough by just enabling email/password signin in firebase console.

You have to do following.

1. Go to 'tools' in android studio:
2. Choose Firebase: it will show a prompt to right side of window.
3. Choose Authentication->Email and Password Authentication.
4. Connect to firebase.
5. It will show a dialog window. -> Choose your existing project to which you want to connect your app. In case you have not signed in firebase with android studio. Then sign in with that email in which you have enabled email/password Authentication.
6. After this Click on 'ADD FIREBASE AUTHENTICATION TO YOUR APP' and again it will show a dialog window. Then click on 'ACCEPT CHANGES'. It will automatically add some
   dependencies and google-services.json file to your project.
7. You are done with configuration in android studio.

NOTE: Add your email address in proper way while creating user. ie: 'xyz@gmail.com'. Sometimes it shows error because of not 'well formed' email address.

Now make your SignIn method in this project and Try to signin again. It will surely work.

Comment: I have it turned on. See updated photo. I think the issue is in my code.